# How to get multi table results of an stored procedure using SimpleJDBCCall in spring?

Tags: java, spring, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jdbc

I'm implementing a `Spring`+ `MSSQL Server 2008` application.
I use `SimpleJDBCCall` API to execute stored procedures and retrieve results.

For stored procedures with mono table results, it works fine, but I don't know how to 
use it for procedures with multi table results.

Sample procedure body:

multi table results

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1
    SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

Answer (score 2):

I was most ignorant, it does in fact work! You can specify both resultsets, with each its own mapper.
In code it looks like this:

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbc)
           .withProcedureName("get_users3")
           .returningResultSet("rs1", new ParameterizedRowMapper<Object[]>()
           {
              @Override
              public Object[] mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException
              {
                 return new Object[] { rowNum, rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2) };
              }
           })
           .returningResultSet("rs2", new ParameterizedRowMapper<Object[]>()
           {
              @Override
              public Object[] mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException
              {
                 return new Object[] { rowNum, rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2) };
              }
           });

  Map<String, Object> res = call.execute();
  assertNotNull(res.get("rs1"));
  assertNotNull(res.get("rs2"));
  List<Object[]> l1 = (List<Object[]>)res.get("rs1");
  List<Object[]> l2 = (List<Object[]>)res.get("rs2");
```

Comment: I have a difficult situation here,i cant change the way database work 
i mean i cant change Store procedures to spilit selects or use SimpleJDBCCall beacuse i get my results from store procedures