# Convert to simplejdbccall resultset to java objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am calling DB2 procedure which takes a input parameter and returns a resultset.
How can i map the O/P to my pojo class.
I have to map the result to nexted pojo classes.

```
    simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbctemplate)
                    .withSchemaName("myschema")
                    .withProcedureName("DB2-PROC")
                    .declareParameters(
                            new SqlParameter("1", Types.VARCHAR)
                        );
                        
    Map<String, Object> map =   simpleJdbcCall.execute("2020-01-01");
    
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println("Entry value  is " + entry.getValue() );
    }
        
        //my o/p
        Entry value  is [{Col_1=abc, col_2=abc,col_2=xyz, col_2=abc},....];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `returningResultSet(parameterName, rowMapper)` method to map values to object.

Here some reference code:

```
SimpleJdbcCall procedureActor = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withSchemaName("myschema")
            .withProcedureName("DB2-PROC")
            .declareParameters(
                    new SqlParameter("1", Types.VARCHAR))
            .returningResultSet("mapObjRefrence", new RowMapper<Contact>() {
     
                @Override
                public Contact mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    YourPojo pojo = new YourPojo();
                     
                    pojo.setId(rs.getInt("col_1"));
                    pojo.setName(rs.getString("col_2"));
                    pojo.setEmail(rs.getString("col_2"));
                    pojo.setAddress(rs.getString("col_3"));
                    pojo.setTelephone(rs.getString("col_4"));
                     
                    return contact;
                }
            });
     
    Map<String, Object> out = procedureActor.execute("2020-01-01");
     
    List<YourPojo> listPojos = (List<YourPojo>) out.get("mapObjRefrence");
```

Also you can check for multi table results: [How to get multi table results using SimpleJDBCCall in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403504/how-to-get-multi-table-results-of-an-stored-procedure-using-simplejdbccall-in-sp)